# Adding Shuffle, Repeat & Random to Android Music Player App

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm working on a open source Android Music player app I'm using some code I found from a tutorial but it doesn't have Shuffle, Repeat & Random buttons included so I need help on adding it to my code. I have no idea how to add it to my app so I'm looking for assistance. I am a complete noob when it comes to Android coding and I'm trying to learn.

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Created by Technologx
 * Visit & signup on https://technologx.com
 * Do not remove this removing this avoids the license
 */

package com.technologx.blaze.player;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO = "com.technologx.blaze.player.PlayNewAudio";

    private MediaPlayerService player;
    boolean serviceBound = false;
    ArrayList<Audio> audioList;

    ImageView collapsingImageView;

    int imageIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        collapsingImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.collapsingImageView);

        loadCollapsingImage(imageIndex);
        loadAudio();
        initRecyclerView();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                playAudio("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Grieg_Lyric_Pieces_Kobold.ogg");
                //play the first audio in the ArrayList
//                playAudio(2);
                if (imageIndex == 4) {
                    imageIndex = 0;
                    loadCollapsingImage(imageIndex);
                } else {
                    loadCollapsingImage(++imageIndex);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void initRecyclerView() {
        if (audioList.size() > 0) {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            RecyclerView_Adapter adapter = new RecyclerView_Adapter(audioList, getApplication());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener(this, new onItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int index) {
                    playAudio(index);
                }
            }));

        }
    }

    private void loadCollapsingImage(int i) {
        TypedArray array = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images);
        collapsingImageView.setImageDrawable(array.getDrawable(i));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        outState.putBoolean("serviceStatus", serviceBound);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        serviceBound = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("serviceStatus");
    }

    //Binding this Client to the AudioPlayer Service
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder binder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder) service;
            player = binder.getService();
            serviceBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    };


    private void playAudio(int audioIndex) {
        //Check is service is active
        if (!serviceBound) {
            //Store Serializable audioList to SharedPreferences
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            storage.storeAudio(audioList);
            storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

            Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
            startService(playerIntent);
            bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        } else {
            //Store the new audioIndex to SharedPreferences
            StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
            storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

            //Service is active
            //Send a broadcast to the service -> PLAY_NEW_AUDIO
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }


    private void loadAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            audioList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (serviceBound) {
             unbindService(serviceConnection);
            //service is active
            player.stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the MusicService.java code:
https://ghostbin.com/paste/x4fyf

I'd like to replace the image shuffle button with a actual shuffle button. I want to add the repeat & random buttons to the menu. Also not in the questions title but how would I go about replacing the images included with the app in the code with the now playing artwork?

Here's the source code to my project with screens: https://github.com/Technologx/Blaze-Player

Answer (score 0):

you should shuffle the list onClick of shuffle method and get the url of song from shuffled list. same goes for others also.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Have you got the list of songs ?

Comment: Yea it displays the list of songs and sorry I'm a noob with Android coding so you'll have to work with me on this.

Comment: after shuffling the list pick 1st song url from list and pass it to Media Player api.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
int position = (Math.Random() * mySongsArray.size());
play(position);
```